# How to create EXACT MATCH using in_array

Tags: php

**This Question has been re-worked to better explain:**

I have a form, with a field called assign to. The field is a SELECT with MULTIPLE enabled. That field is being hooked by Jquery's autocomplete. The OPTIONS consist of an employee list, as the form is a "follow-up" ticket generator and a ticket can be assigned to multiple employees for follow-up.

The OPTIONS list is being generated by a PHP query from database getting all records from table EMPLOYEES, The OPTIONS list is made by a ECHO statement inside a WHILE LOOP. each option consists of this `<option value='$rowx[employeeid],$rowx[employeename]' $keyx>$rowx[group] - $rowx[employeename]</option>`

This form when in a BLANK state works just fine, but the same form is used and PRE-POPULATED with data when a user is trying to EDIT a follow-up ticket as opposed to creating a new one.

In order to PER-POPULATE the MULTI-SELECT: the database has a field called `assignto` consisting of employee ID numbers (comma separated) that the follow-up being edited has been previously assigned to: Thus by example [assignto]="2345,234567,34657,32432" (Thats 4 different employees it has been tasked too)

The code below is whats generating the options list, the INTENT was that if `$rowx['employeeid']` matches any value that was already in the `assignto` row from the database then THAT OPTION would have the SELECTED attribute added to it. Thus giving me a per-populated multi-select. The Problem: When editing a follow-up where employee "234567" was assigned, the SELECTED is being added to 2 option fields. John doe - Employee #2345 & Jim Doe - Employee #234567 because PHP `in_array` isn't looking for explicitly "23456", but instead is looking for  <---- "23456" ---->

```
<select name="assignto[]" type="text" class="mselects" multiple="multiple" style="width:460px; overflow:hidden;">
<?php
$equery = "SELECT `employeeid`,`employeename`,`group` FROM `employees` WHERE `status` = 'A' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$equery);
$litmus = explode(",",$row['assignto']);
while ($rowx = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$keyx = array_search($rowx['employeeid'], $litmus);
if ($keyx >= 0) {$keyx = "selected";}
echo "<option value='$rowx[employeeid],$rowx[employeename]' $keyx>$rowx[group] - $rowx[employeename]</option>";
unset($keyx);
}
 ?>
</select>
```

Comment: in_array returns a bool. using your  $litmus it returns 1 = true. If I remove the '23456' it returns a 0 = false.

Comment: @JasonK thing is Jason I tried checking against the bool before `if (in_array($rowx['employeeid'],$litmus) == 1){ $sval="selected";}` but it's still returning TRUE on other values from $litmus because "23456" matches to both $litmus[0] as well as $litmus[1]

Comment: When using array_search you have to check the type on the return var. Not just the value. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your check if ($keyx >= 0) will always eval to true.

```
if ($keyx !== false)
```

Comment: No, but I have rebuilt the question in an effort to better explain

Comment: Well, some of what you said before wasn't a direct answer however your answers did get me looking at a different approach. Since array_search() will return a `Integer` value for every TRUE, then I went with this successfully. `if (is_int($keyx)) {$keyx = "selected";}` I'm going to accept yours since you stuck with trying to help answer it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($value in $litmus) {
    if ($value==$rowx['employeeid']) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jason told you, in_array returns a boolean when the array contains the value you want on any of its elements.

You may want to look at array_search().